# Flash Builder ASDoc @see tag with redirect

Tags: flash, comments, tooltip, flash-builder, asdoc

Is it possible to set up the asdoc @see tag in Flash Builder 4 so when I click on the generated link in the tooltip it would take me to the corresponding line of code (function, variable, class etc.)?

I know that this happens in the generated asdoc html files, but I would like it to happen inside Flash Builder, when I hover with the mouse over a function name, for example. When the asdoc tooltip appears (containing text I've previously written and a @see tag), I would like to click on the link generated by @see and it would take me there.

If this doesn't work for @see, is there another tag or something else that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you searching for something like this? Somehow you access class attributes and methods as if they were static elements. Could be improved, i guess. *Nicholas

```
package de.goldsource.test
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    /**
     * ASDocTest
     * @see flash.display.Sprite
     * @see ASDocTest.ASDocTest()
     * */
    public class ASDocTest extends Sprite
    {
        /**
         * ASDocTest Constructor
         * @see ASDocTest.myVar
         * @see ASDocTest.myFunction()
         * @see ASDocTest.myStaticFunction()
         * */
        public function ASDocTest(){

        }

        /**
         * myVar
         * */
        public var myVar;           

        /**
         * myFunction        
         * */
        public function myFunction():void
        {
        }

        /**
         * myStaticFunction      
         * */
        public static function myStaticFunction():void
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. For me, it wasn't working because I had no ASDoc comments for the methods and vars I was trying to click in the tooltip. What FB has implemented is not exactly what I was looking for, because when I click the @see generated link, it opens the ASDoc tooltip for the respective item, and then I have a button which I can use to get to the declaration. Unfortunately, for uncommented items I can't do this. Also, it's enough to place a "#" before the name of the item, no need to write the class name. Ex: '@see #myStaticFunction This is the description'

Comment: Anyway, it's better than nothing. In some way, it's better than what I wanted, because I have the option to get a quick peek at the item description. It would be nice if FB would generate some ad-hoc ASDoc, like the method name and type, so I can go to the declaration of uncommented items. Anyway, thank you very much.